# Block website Visitors to open a new tab/window

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, web

I am Planning for online quiz for the students using wordpress platform . I want that when any student login to the site, the quiz page appears, and then if he tries to minimize the window, open a new tab or a new browser the quiz should be be off/blocked/restart. or the new tab or window could be restricted or the quiz window could not be minimized in any case.

Is there any Plugin or Script or any way..?

Comment: Write a desktop app that basically hijacks the computer and ruins lives. There's no way to do this in a webscript. Imagine all the viagra we'd have to buy if this was possible.

Comment: Very helpful comments, well done guys! That's how all high-rep users should welcome the newcomers...

Answer (score 1):

The closest thing you can do is to detect if the window has lost focus (by minimizing, opening something else, etc...), using the [blur](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.onblur) event in JavaScript and then handle it the way you want:

```
window.addEventListener( 'blur', function(){
    alert('Hey, focus lost!');
});
```

Here is a simple example showing how a counter gets reset when the result window loses focus (don't forget to first click inside the results window to gain focus if you don't have it): http://jsfiddle.net/kgufU/1/

You probably won't need to worry about gaining focus the first time. It happens on jsfiddle because the results window is an iframe.

Comment: In addition, you can use this event to log how many times the user switches windows while taking a quiz. Just don't assume that a blur event automatically means they're running to wikipedia to find answers. I often skip around sites while waiting for repos to commit or code to compile.

Comment: I'd rather warn them in the beginning that the cheating will be punished and then remove points/close the quiz for everyone who is away for a few seconds (because sometimes there can be an unexpected popup or something showing up that will take away the focus, so we can't punish them the same moment they switch away).